# Manage Fault Tolerance with Feign, Ribbon and Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, ribbon, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I want to implement a resilient microservices architecture using Feign Client,Ribbon and Eureka so I encountered an issue. When a microservices target is down I want to redirect to another instance of microservices without the user seeing it. For example, I have 4 instances of microservices B and one instance A :

The Browser client call A then A call B1 but B1 is down => A redirect automatically to B2, B2 is KO then A call B3 and B3 is up then it returns a response to A. A returns response to the browser client.

How I could implement it, please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Ribbon should already find instances that are alive for you - firstly, Eureka stores and updates information on which instances are alive and, secondly, Ribbon runs [health-check requests to the instances](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Features). If that is not working correctly for you, you can try [customising the polling intervals for Ribbon](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.x/reference/html/#customizing-the-ribbon-client). If you want a failed request to be repeated against a different instance, you can use Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon with Spring Retry (see [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.x/reference/html/#retrying-failed-requests)).

Having said that, since Spring Cloud Ribbon [is now in maintenance mode and will not be making it into the 2020.0.0 release train](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now), I would definitely not encourage adding it at this point. The available alternative is [Spring Cloud LoadBalancer](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.x/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer). It supports retrieving the instances that are alive from Service Discovery (either with or without [caching](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.x/reference/html/#loadbalancer-caching) and [health-checks](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/2.2.x/reference/html/#instance-health-check-for-loadbalancer). It does not support retries at this point, but there's an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/659) for it in the project backlog.

Comment: "If you want a failed request to be repeated against a different instance, you can use Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon with Spring Retry"  Thanks you !